# How to change pages in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

How can I easily change pages in the MAUI app? I have tried to do it change pages via Navigation property but is it any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to change pages in the MAUI app.

**Change page by Routing:**
To change page by routing u have to:

1. Create new ContentPage (XAML)

[image]

2. Register the route of the page you want to change in AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyApp.View.MyPage), typeof(MyApp.View.MyPage));
    }
```

3. Create the method that will be called upon an event that will call GoToAsync(nameof(MyApp.View.MyPage))

```
private async void GoToAnotherPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MyApp.View.MyPage)); 
        }
```

4. Now after calling this method your program will redirect you to another page.

**Change page by Navigation property**: To change page by Navigation property you have to:

1. Create new ContentPage (XAML)

[image]

2. Create the method that will be called upon an event that will call PushAsync(new MyApp.View.MyPage). Navigation property is a property inherited from ContentPage, to use it you have to create a method inside a class that derives from ContentPage (all Pages) or pass it to another class for example via the class constructor.

```
private void GoToAnotherPage()
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MyApp.View.MyPage());
        }
```

3. Now after calling this method your program will redirect you to another page.